# Pandas dataframe.to_sql create a column by name "INDEX" and mysql is not able to process it's column name="index"

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I did df.to_sql(name='phishingdataset',con=con,if_exists='append',index=False)

where in my dataset there is no column by name "index" where as when it creates the table in mysql it does creates one column by this name.
And when I try to access this column it throws error.

I tried to search the docs and mysql docs but there is not such reference of this kind.

```
df.to_sql(name='phishingdataset',con=con,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

In mysql query:-

```
select * from phishingdataset where index=1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index=1' at line 1
```

Where my schema is :-

```
+-----------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| index                       | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| having_IPhaving_IP_Address  | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| URLURL_Length               | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Shortining_Service          | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| having_At_Symbol            | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| double_slash_redirecting    | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Prefix_Suffix               | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| having_Sub_Domain           | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SSLfinal_State              | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Domain_registeration_length | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Favicon                     | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| port                        | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| HTTPS_token                 | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Request_URL                 | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| URL_of_Anchor               | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Links_in_tags               | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SFH                         | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Submitting_to_email         | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Abnormal_URL                | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Redirect                    | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| on_mouseover                | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RightClick                  | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| popUpWidnow                 | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Iframe                      | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age_of_domain               | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DNSRecord                   | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| web_traffic                 | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Page_Rank                   | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Google_Index                | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Links_pointing_to_page      | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Statistical_report          | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Result                      | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
32 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `index` is a reserved word in pretty much any SQL-compliant database. In MySQL, you can wrap the name in backticks when referencing. Now why Pandas creates this column in `to_sql` is a different and curious question. What is in the content? The data frame's index?

Comment: ah , data frame's content , it actually has a header by the name index , but I already dropped that column before inserting to db. And which is why it's weird that this .to_sql created one on it's own even after setting index=false. Now that it's created what can be the query to access this index?

Comment: Did you re-assign data frame when you dropped the column? Please post this `drop` line. Also, I just mentioned to wrap *index* in backticks in your query because it is a reserved word.

Comment: I did not reassigned the data-frame , that was a mistake. I thought I do not need to do so. But now it's done and is working fine. Thanks for helping. :)